# How to 'source' another file in a Bash script run on EMR

Tags: bash, amazon-emr

Is there a way when running a step in AWS EMR to 'source' another file in a bash script?

For example, this is a script, let's call it 'run.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh
source $1
echo $VAR1" "$VAR2
exit0
```

Then have another file, call it 'parms.sh':

```
VAR1=this
VAR2=that
```

Then run from AWS EMR step:

```
aws emr add-steps \
--cluster-id 123 \
--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,\
Name="Script Test",\
ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,\
Jar=s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,\
Args=[s3://mybucket/run.sh,"s3://mybucket/parms.sh"]
```

This error exits as soon as it hits the 'source' statement. I assume it can't 'source' from S3 for some reason?

Comment: Indeed, the argument to `source` must be a local file. No S3, HTTP, or carrier pigeon support.

Comment: As an aside, you generally want quotes _around_ your variables, not between them.

Answer (score 0):

So sourcing from S3 can't work, which I suppose make sense on some level. Looked a little closer at EMR docs, and it seems the solution is to copy both files to somewhere on the cluster as part of the step then execute:

```
aws emr add-steps \
--cluster-id 123 \
--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,\
Name="Script Test",\
ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,\
Jar=s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,\
Args=[/usr/bin/bash,-c,"aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/run.sh /home/hadoop; \
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/parms.sh /home/hadoop; 
/usr/bin/chmod u+x /home/hadoop/run.sh; \
/usr/bin/chmod u+x /home/hadoop/parms.sh; \
cd /home/hadoop; 
./run.sh ./parms.sh"]
```